How can I verify the source code of a solana program?
If there is an on-chain program, how do I verify that the compiled code in there is actually what it claims to be?

If you're using anchor, you can use anchor build --verifiable to generate a verifiable build and then verify it later using anchor verify -p <lib-name> <program-id>. More info on this here.
The disadvantage is, this works under the hood by rebuilding the whole program and comparing each byte of the compiled program with what's onchain, which is quite inefficient and inaccessible to non-technical users.
A more modern way to do this is to use verifiable-build. This uses a hash for verification, so it makes verification significantly more efficient (though a bit more trusted if you don't bother to recompute the hash yourself). Additionally, it also works for non-anchor programs.
Source for all this is from this twitter thread.
